# How convert HTML to LaTeX or MathML

Tags: conversion, html, mathml

I using KaTeX to render HTML formula display.
How can I convert HTML to LaTeX or KaTeX again?

Comment: Welcome! What's KaTeX?

Comment: I use this to render html display https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX

Comment: don't you still have the tex-like input that you passed to katex? you can't really do a reverse translation from the html/css that the javascript produces.

Comment: So do you know what solution in this demo of wiris :http://www.wiris.com/editor/demo/en/mathml-latex

Comment: in what way is that related to your question? it isn't converting from html (its internal form is structured mathml0)and it doesn't use katex unless it's changed recently.

Comment: My problem is how when change the formula display then change the latex formula too

Comment: but there you are editing _input_ you are not editing generated html/css, it's not possible in general to go in the other direction, just like the common question of how to get tex source back from a pdf file.

Comment: Do you have other solution for me? I making tool can add and edit math formula. Now I can display formula by katex rendering but can't edit it. thank you  David Carlisle!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convert HTML to LaTeX?

You can use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). It does a good job if your HTML is clean, i.e. doesn't have many `div`'s and `span`'s.

About KaTeX, you first need to understand that KaTeX is only a Javascript library to convert the math subset of LaTeX to something that will be render at web browsers. If you have the original source code of your HTML page that has the LaTeX code instead of the KaTeX output I believe that Pandoc will solve your problem (and if not please report the issue at http://github.com/jgm/pandoc/). If you only have the KaTeX output Pandoc will not solve your problem.